# Calling Java Method from Android NDK SIGSEGV

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to call a java method from NDK code. the C++ code is:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_com_lipman_whiteboard_CameraProcessing_processBitmap(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{
jclass callingClass = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(callingClass, "setProgressMax", "(I)V");
env->CallVoidMethod(obj, mid, 7);
}
```

"mid" is always null in the above snippet. The relevant parts of the java class are:

```
public class CameraProcessing
{
private static native boolean processBitmap();

private void setProgressMax(int max)
{
}
```

Does anyone know why "mid" is always null? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey there, gonna be the boring one and say are you using proguard?

Comment: you should probably add a "JNI" tag to this, seeing as that is what you are using here. I'd try to help but it's been a while since I did JNI myself... only thing I can think of is that you have not shown your initialisation code for the `env` pointer.

Comment: because the function is private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared the native `processBitmap()` method to be static, which means the second argument is a `jclass` rather than a `jobject`.  When you call `GetObjectClass`, you're actually getting the class of the `jclass`, which means `callingClass` is simply `java.lang.Class`, which does not define a `setProgressMax` method.  There should be an exception pending with a message to that effect.

Change the declaration to:

```
private native boolean processBitmap();
```

and try again.

Calling a private method should not be a problem from JNI.

Also, make sure you check for exceptions after `CallVoidMethod` returns.